# Node-red Catching error node-red-contrib-ab

Tags: node-red, plc

I'm using node-red-contrib-ab to read PLC data,
Whenever the plc is off, this node throws a message in debug window

> Failure (Bad values)

- I want to catch this error so that i can send a signal to database.
- I have used the catch node but no luck, Is there any way i can catch the error and
  store it into msg.payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Catch node to work, the node needs to be reporting the errors using the [proper API](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-js#handling-errors). If you are only getting a log message and nothing from the Catch node, that means the node needs fixing.

However, the node you mention, node-red-contrib-ab has not been updated for 2 years and has no github link associated with it for reporting issues. You would have to contact the author directly to ask if they can make the change.

Alternatively, I see that node is actually an old fork of https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-s7 which is more widely used and actively maintained. You may want to see if you can switch to that module for your particular PLC.

Comment: thanks for response, can you tell me how the catch node catches an exception, i mean how it identifies that a particular node throws an exception.

Comment: I linked to the api docs that describe what the node must do to log an error for the Catch node to handle.